# Obligation to call a method

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, warnings, compiler-warnings

In VB .NET, when you create a user control class, you have the obligation to call the sub InitializeComponent within the constructor.

If you don't you'll a warning message like this :

> 'Public Sub New()' in
>   designer-generated type
>   'MyUserControl' should call
>   InitializeComponent method.

What is the mechanism used to raise this warning?  Is it something I can reproduce for my own functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is built-in behavior for the VB.NET compiler.  This sample class triggers it:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub New()
       '' Warning BC40054 generated here
    End Sub
End Class
```

The attribute matters.  It is not otherwise generically useful behavior, you cannot tell the compiler to make it generate a similar warning using your own attribute.