# Replacing Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()

Tags: c#

I am converting a VB.NET project over to C#.  After the conversion I still have some outstanding issues to deal with.  One is the left over DesignerGenerated() attribute.

> [Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()]
>
> internal partial class Tags : ServiceBase {
>
> ...

I do not want to just reference the VisualBasic assembly to make this code happy.  I don't want any remenence of VB period.  So I don't know how to replace this attribute with an equivilant C# attribute here.  It looks like this DesignerGenerated() is only used in VB.NET so not sure how to resolve this and convert it to some C# equivalent.

Comment: Man after my own heart.

Comment: I just want to mention that if someone is interested how to be able to use `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices` he should add a reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`. Reference: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft/VisualBasic/CompilerServices/Conversions.cs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only the VB.NET compiler ever checks for this attribute.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817836/obligation-to-call-a-method/4817943#4817943) for the reason it exists.

You can safely remove it.

Comment: I removed mine and I got this exception.  DmainEventsProjectServiceDesigner.cs could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Also check [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529311.aspx#Y2385) as well. This attribute is just available for VB.NET